# What the error message means?

Tags: weka

Hi I have a csv file with text value and nominal , coming from an Excel spreadsheet saved as CSV. I have some problem with \ and some commas but after correct them I receive the message
"java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsExceptions:33" and I can't understand htis error message. Can someone help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Antonio the error message indicates that your database is expecting 32 results but your spreadsheet has 33 (or more).
You can try to check if you didn't misscount the amount of data you have or if you didnt have a white cell in the middle of your spreadsheet

Comment: Thanks, this is correct I double checkt he file and I found that there was a white celle.